# How do I determine limits and requests for cpu and memory with know prior data

Tags: kubernetes

Fairly new to kubernetes, I have a question about setting `limits` and `requests` in regards to `CPU` and `Memory`. If I have a few applications in my cluster but none of these applications are in production how do I determine the correct way to set the `limits` and `requests` for the applications in the cluster with know prior data.

I tried the `kubectl top pods -n <namespace>` but this only gave me the current usage, wondering if anyone had any suggestions of a logical way to set the `limits` and `requests`?

Comment: The `logical way` is to come up with a usage dataset consisting of all production-like scenarios, check the usage peaks, and decide. Typically done per application Biases by the application owner.  Many times tools like `Prometheus` makes things easier.(although not necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you executed kubectl top -n namespace and found pod is consuming 50m CPU and 230MB of memory. (Assuming the pod is running in a development/staging environment and it's idle - not processing any requests) you can use this data in **requests** as this is the minimum amount of resource which is required to run this pod, If had to set request I would have set 50m CPU and 256MB of Memory.

To set limits you should ask a tester to make 100 requests and meanwhile watch ⌚ load using kubectl top command (Suppose you saw pod is consuming 170m CPU and 400MB memory) Now subtract it with idle pod resources.

170m  - 50m    = 120m
400MB - 230MB  = 170MB

120m CPU and 170MB of Memory are required to serve 100 requests.

Now as per your requirements you can set limits.

For more information visit https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

Answer (score 1):

To determine request and limits, you can try the vertical pod autoscaler : https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler

You have two main modes :

- `off` : give informations about request and limits during the pod life.
- `recreate` : recreate the pod with new request and limits (when needed)